# Convert ByteArray to HTML file in angular JS

Tags: html, arrays, angularjs, type-conversion

I generated a HTML file from ASPOSE workbook and saved it into memory stream in C# and now I want to display this HTML file in Angular JS inside the Div element.

C# Code:

```
wb.Save(htmlMemoryStream, new HtmlSaveOptions() { IsExportComments = true});
htmlMemoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
htmlBytes = htmlMemoryStream.ToArray();
```

angular JS Code:

```
if (data.length > 0) {
vm.hasBeenExported = true;
vm.File = data[0].htmlFile;
}

<div ng-bind-html="vm.File "></div>
```

But its not working

Answer (score 0):

By default, multiple files are generated when rendering to HTML from Excel workbook. Maybe your issue is due to those multiple files on angular js. I think you may try to generate single html file based on single sheet in the workbook. You should instantiate and specify the relevant option, i.e., set HtmlSaveOptions.SaveAsSingleFile to generate single html file based on the active sheet. Give it a try if it fixes your issue.

You can also post your queries or issue in dedicated [forums](https://forum.aspose.com/c/cells/9).

PS. I am working as Support developer/ Evangelist at Aspose.